# How to make groups in an input and select a specific row in each of them in Talend?

Tags: etl, talend

I am working on a Talend transformation process (we are using Talend 6.4).
, and I don't know how to implement the current requirement.

I have an input consisting in :

- Two columns that are my group keys (Account and Product), but are not unique (the same Account x Product couple can happen in multiple rows)
- A criterion column (Contract end date), which will help me decide which row I want to keep for each group
- Some "tail" data that need to be passed to the following step of the processing (the contract number)

The rule to implement is:

- Keep only one record per group
- The selected record must be one with no end date or, if all have end date, with the biggest end date
- The selected record can be random in case there is a tie

See the transformation applying those rules on some dummy data:
[image: Description of the transformation]

I thought first to do the following:

1. sort by Account, Product, End_date (nulls first)
2. "select first" in each group

but I am not skilled enough to know whether the second transformation exists in Talend.

[image: description of this solution]

Regards,

Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting Talend question.
You need to create something like this job.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[here a link to the zip file to import in your Talend](http://www.filedropper.com/topnrowpergroup01)

Comment: Thanks for this very accurate answer. We do not have the chance to test this specific way of doing it, because another developper came up with a slightly different approach that did work (I will add another answer to describe what we did). If you have the time, can you please describe the pros an cons of each solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @MBDIA seem to be working, however I would like to share what we did to fulfill our requirement.

See our Talend process here:

[image: Batch description]

The first tMap (tMap_3) acts like a tReplicate and a tMap, and sends:

- in the upper branch only the Account and Product references, that are then deduplicated by the tAggregateRow_1.
- in the lower branch all data and computed fields that enables us to take care of the case where the date is missing (instead of defaulting to 31/12/9999, we compute a flag (0 or 1) that we use in the sort step afterwards).

In the second part of the process, we first apply the sort to the whole data on Account, Product, Empty date flag (computed before), End date (desc) and use a second tMap to make a join on both branches (on Account x Product), only keeping **First Match** in order to keep the first record as per our requirement.

Comment: I tested your answer, and it also worked perfectly. Your solution rely on the TMAP match model. It is a different approach, I really like it because it uses less talend components. The only advantage that my solution has over yours is that with my solution, you will not have to change anything apart the condition used in tfilter_row_2 component  when you need to get more than the first one rows (the first n rows where n could be 2, 3, 4, and so on ).
Thank you for sharing it.